# How to showing details data Excel in one column

Tags: excel-formula

For example, I have 2 tables in Excel:

[image]

I want to display like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In cell `C2` use `UNIQUE(A2:A5)`
In cell `D2` use `=TEXTJOIN("; ",1,FILTER(B2:B5,A2:A5=C2))`

(provided that your data is in `A2:B5` and you have Office 365)

The first formula extracts the distinct values from column A.
The second formula combines the text in column B if the value in column A matches the value in the same row of column C and separates these values with `;` .